# crash your application HEAP size using JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, out-of-memory

I use a lot of JSON for data processing. Recently while working on such, I encountered a strange problem which ended up in OEM.(out of memory).

```
String myInData = "[one,two,three,";
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(myInData);
```

If you run the above code, it will exceed the heap space( if the application runs in auto GC).

On certain conditions, I can not expect the data to be in proper format and I can not check each key value to be in proper format. Is there any way to check if the JSONArray String is proper and valid?

Comment: What library does JSONArray come from? I would say that any JSON library should validate the JSON, and shouldn't cause any OOME with such an invalid JSON. If it's indeed all it takes to get an OOME with this JSON library, it just has a huge bug that needs to be signalled and fixed.

Comment: OEM means Original Equipment Manufacturer - http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/oem.asp.  You mean OOME ... OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @JBNizet yes, I use JSON library.

Comment: Huge bug ... as in "vector for denial of service attacks"!!!

Comment: @kiddo - WHICH library?

Comment: I would suggest you to increase heap size for your application, or else try an efficient way.

Comment: @kiddo the question is "which one"? There are dozens of JSON parsers in Java. And half of them have a class named JSONArray.

Comment: @kiddo **Which** JSON library?

Comment: Caution: it is also possible that kiddo's application is to blame.  We really need an SSCCE before we pass judgement ...

Comment: @StephenC Somehow I also doubt this. The parser should throw up on the second character, I think.

Comment: @lexicore - Agreed.  See my answer.

Comment: Guys, please see my comment in @StephenC answer. I tried with newer version and it worked.. it throws parser error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this.

When I run the following against the latest org.json JAR from GoogleCode, I get a JSON exception complaining about a syntax error.  No OOME.

```
[steve@newbox tmp]$ cat Test.java 
import org.json.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String myInData = "[one,two,three,";
    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(myInData);
    }
}
[steve@newbox tmp]$ javac -cp org.json-20120521.jar Test.java
[steve@newbox tmp]$ java -cp org.json-20120521.jar:. Test
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Missing value at 15 [character 16 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:387)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:144)
    at Test.main(Test.java:6)
[steve@newbox tmp]$
```

---

Conclusion: either you have a "dodgy" JAR file, or the actual cause of the OOMEs in your code is something else; e.g. something that happens after you attempted (and failed) to parse the JSON.

Comment: I used the jar which has the below build details in META-INF
  Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
  Created-By: 1.6.0-b105 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
And I tried the same in 
 2 Created-By: 1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
      and it seems to throw the parser error

Comment: But note that it fails on 15th character and *not* on the 2nd character. From the grammar perspective it could have failed on the 2nd character as it does not match any production, as far as I can see. So there might be some truth in the report.

Comment: The build details are uninformative.  What is the file name / version number of the JAR file, and where did you get it from?

Comment: I do not have that info, its within our org download list. I tried the latest downloaded jar , do not have the source link :(